# Calling a method when initializing a default value for a field in a dataclass

Tags: python, python-dataclasses

When setting up a default value for an attribute, I'm able to call a function that's been defined outside the class, but not a method defined within it.

Please see examples below.

Imports:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
```

`call_that()` defined outside works fine:

```py
def call_that():
  return -1

@dataclass
class Foo:
  myvar : int = field(default_factory = call_that)

Foo()
```

returns "Foo(myvar=-1)"

But `call_this()` defined inside

```py
@dataclass
class Foo:
  myvar : int = field(default_factory = call_this)
  def call_this():
    return 1

Foo()
```

returns "NameError: name 'call_this' is not defined"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must define the „method“ before assigning or otherwise using it:

```
@dataclass
class Foo:
  # method precedes its usage
  def call_this():
    return 1

  myvar : int = field(default_factory = call_this)

Foo()
```

---

Take note that this is not a proper method, even though it is defined in the class body. It does not (and should not) take a `self` parameter - it can only be meaningfully used through the class, not any instances. However, it will still end up as part of the public interface of every instance.

Consider to `del` the method at the end of the class body, or just to use an external function, to avoid polluting your class‘ interface.

Comment: What if it does take self though? How to make it work then?

Comment: @MoteZart There is no self while the body of a class is evaluated. What you are asking about is fundamentally a different thing.